# Eclipse Debugger Problem: com.sun.jdi.ObjectCollectedException occurred while retrieving value

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I am using the following Eclipse, **2019-03 (March):**

[image]

```
Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)
Build id: 20190314-1200
```

I'm unable to debug properly because randomly, out of the blue, when click on Variables or Expressions, the window suddenly becomes this:

[image]

Please note that I tried playing with this setting, **both On and Off**, as suggested in some threads, but it didn't help:

[image]

*Show Method Result After a Step Operation*

Any other ideas?

Comment: Possibly Eclipse bug [537399](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=537399) The comments there have some suggestions

Comment: In other words, no resolution. I don't want to uncheck `Logical Structures` in the Debug-View, that's the whole point - to see my logical structures. Note that there are NO problems in previous Eclipses, like Eclipse Neon.3.

Comment: @geneb. Did you ever have any luck with this? I've tried to figure out what's wrong to no avail. Ended up learning to live with the problem. Are you using Java 11? I am and have sort of assumed that the GC1 is collecting memory at the references that I wish to inspect.

Comment: We have to live with the problem, yes. Eclipse 03-2020 has this to a lesser extent than 03-2019, it's a little better, but still has it occasionally. I am using Java 11. They broke Eclipse sometime around 2019; before that the debugger used to work 100%. They never really fixed it after that 2019 breakage.

Comment: Everyone, "I can confirm that this bug STILL exists in 2020-06 (4.16.0). They haven't fixed it yet! Source: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=537399#c42  Unbelievable!

Answer (score 2):

Solved this issue with possible work-around.

1. Right click on the variable and go to the "**Show Logical Structure**" field.
   [image]
2. Uncheck the "**Array**" field.
   [image]

3. Validate the variable now. Hope this will show the your corresponding results.